# Google Maps API use zoom level and center position from local storage values to adjust map on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, local-storage

I am working with a WordPress/jQuery/Google Maps setup to display a map of listings to users.

The `jQuery.goMap.map` code is used to load in the Google Maps instance used on the WordPress plugin.

I have wrote the following functions to store and load the latitude, longitude, and zoom level with local storage. The storing of the lat/lng and zoom levels is working, and the loading of the zoom level is working, but I cannot get the map to center on the loaded latitude and longitude position.

I have tried using `bounds.extend(latLng);` and `jQuery.goMap.map.fitBounds(bounds);` in the `loadUserZoom` function, but the result is a fully zoomed in map. This means the stored zoom level value is being ignored.

The current functioning code can be [tested here](https://staging.callkneehill.ca/visitors/).

The Clear text link in the header navigation can be used to clear the local storage values from the browser. This is implemented for testing purposes.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

**Function: storeUserZoom**

```
function storeUserZoom() {
  let zoom = jQuery.goMap.map.getZoom();
  localStorage.setItem( 'zoom', zoom);
  let center = jQuery.goMap.map.getCenter();
  let lat = center.lat();
  let lng = center.lng();
  let latLng = {
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng
  }
  localStorage.setItem( 'latLng', JSON.stringify(latLng));
}
```

**Function: loadUserZoom**

```
function loadUserZoom() {
  if (localStorage.getItem( 'zoom' )) {
    let zoom = parseInt(localStorage.getItem( 'zoom' ));
    console.log(zoom);
    // Logs correct zoom level
    let latLng = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( 'latLng' ));
    console.log(latLng);
    // Logs Object { lat: 51.69124213478852, lng: -113.2478200914128 }
    jQuery.goMap.map.setZoom(zoom);
    jQuery.goMap.map.setCenter(latLng);
    // latLng used is incorrect
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue **in the question itself** (preferably a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)), not (just) a link to an external site that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Your code works with the native Google Maps JavaScript API v3; ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s2vm6wtj/2/).) if you can make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue with the `goMap` library, someone might be able to determine why that doesn't work.  Looking at your link, I don't see any useful errors, or know where you expect the center to be (the comment says it is wrong, why do you believe that?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have zeroed in on the problem by adjusting how the `loadUserZoom` function was executed in the `initMap` function.

The `loadUserZoom` function was wrapped in a Google Maps listen once event listener when the map was idle. The code is included below.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(jQuery.goMap.map, 'idle', function() {
  loadUserZoom();
});
```

I had it set initially to `addListener`, which seemed to conflict with the required functionality. I assume this meant it was execute regularly whenever the map was in an idle state.

My updated `loadUserZoom` function is included below.

```
function loadUserZoom() {
  if (localStorage.getItem( 'zoom' )) {
    let zoom = parseInt(localStorage.getItem( 'zoom' ));
    let latLng = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( 'latLng' ));
    jQuery.goMap.map.setZoom(zoom);
    jQuery.goMap.map.setCenter(latLng);
  }
}
```